# Short number or company name in the message information

Tags: sms, twilio

I want to know if there is a way to send a text message, but that the recipient when receiving it does not receive it from the regular number with which the account is registered, that is, the telephone number that Twilio provides, in this case that is a short number, it would even be much better if it were with the name of my company.

Examples when receiving a message:

**Phone number: COMPANY NAME**

**Body: Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.**

**Number: 5897**

**Body: Lorem ipsum pain sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.**

Comment: Hi Jorge welcome to stackoverflow. To get questions answered in the community is best to ask questions that include the code and research that you have tried already and where you are getting stuck. General questions tend to get down voted, and are considered off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do both with Twilio!

The cheaper version is sending from your company name. This is known as an alphanumeric sender ID and you can see [how to send a message from an alphanumeric sender ID in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/send-branded-sms-messages-using-twilio-alphanumeric-sender-id.html). Warning, using alphanumeric sender IDs only works in certain countries (around 145 of them), you can see [which countries support alphanumeric sender IDs here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID). You can [use a messaging service to fallback from an alphanumeric sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133867-Using-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-with-Messaging-Services) to a regular number to cope with this.

You can also use short codes. These work like regular numbers within Twilio, they just come with some more regulatory issues and cost a lot more. Checkout [our resources on short codes here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's just what I was looking for.

Unfortunately there is no support for my country.
Thank you very much in advance, Regards.